# Setting maxPostSize in grails

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am trying to set maxPostSize (tomcats server.xml  property) in grails. How should I do this?

Comment: What version of Grails and what version of Tomcat are you running?

Comment: Already found it: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/tomcat-plugin-where-is-server-xml-and-tomcat-users-xml-td1322273.html :)

Comment: @LinasLitvinas Please add your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Already found it: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/tomcat-plugin-where-is-server-xml-and-tomcat-users-xml-td1322273.html

Comment: This link is not working. Could you add some details on how did you solve this?